# Integrate Jenkins to a private repository

Tags: git, github, jenkins, continuous-integration

I've trying to integrate jenkins to a private repository of my organization. Here's what I've tried:

- First approach: Use the Credentials plugin to put my github username and password.
  [image]
- Second approach: Go to github and generate and access token, then add it as secret text 
  credential in jenkins.
  [image]
  [image]
  [image]

**Note in the last picture that even though I added the secret text credential, it doesn't appear in my options. Although it is added to the global credentials when I go to `Jenkins -> Credentials`. So I'm not sure if it is using it or not.**

- Third approach: [Add a deploy key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32030922/how-to-clone-a-private-repository-of-github-organization-in-a-jenkins-job) to the repository with server's ssh public key. If you have more than one public key like me, [create a host alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212304/authenticate-jenkins-ci-for-github-private-repository)

`vi ~/.ssh/config`

[image: ~/.ssh/config]

[image]

I also tried without alias:

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: With your third approach (which i have got working for private repos in the past), it looks like your hostname may be set incorrectly  - what is `github-droid`? It should be `github.com`

Comment: @PeterReid I had to do that because I have two public keys in my repository. One for my droid repository and the default for ios. So I had to create an alias to tell jenkins which public key it should use for the android repository. I edited my answer tho show you my `~/.ssh/config`